# Dependency Injection using @produce in Tomcat 7 [Injectin object not found]

Tags: java, dependency-injection, java-ee-6, cdi

I asked this question before,but I have done some major changes from my previous code.I am trying to Inject an object in web-app using the @Inject annotation from Java EE 6.I am injecting a String object using the @Produce,further I am using @Qualifier.I am running this in Tomcat 7,which I read that doesnt support CDI as it is mainly a servlet container and not a full fledge Java EE container,So i tried adding the Weld into it.

Class where I inject using @Inject

```
@Path("login")
public class Login{

@Inject
@Config
  private String name;
 //do somthing with String name
 }
```

My Producer Class

```
 import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
 public class ConfigurationFactory {

  @Produces @Config
   public String getName() {
    return "XYZ";
   }
}
```

I used a Qualifier

```
@Target( { TYPE, METHOD, PARAMETER, FIELD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
public @interface Config {
}
```

I read in many post in stackoverflow and outside materials and Java EE 6 specifications.I followed this structure but I still get this error

```
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at Injectee
```

Since tomcat doesn't support CDI, I added the weld using this POM depedency
This is my Pom.xml

```xml
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.10.Final</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.1</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
```

I added an empty Beans.xml file under the WEB-INF directory as suggested in the oracle site.

I am not sure why this occurred,so I tried to analyze the problem and added a empty bean.xml file in under the WEB-INF directory and also I tried binding the resource file "ConfigurationFactory" using astractBinder .Any suggestion?

Comment: Adding weld to the project won't automatically make it CDI enabled.

Comment: Read here: [How to install CDI in Tomcat?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-install-cdi-in-tomcat.html)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza tried the link you suggested,tomcat started fine without any exception,but still I get the org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:

Comment: Is this problem exactly the same I'm facing with solved?